# CMS-Initial-Mark GC Pause is increasing

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

We have recently migrated an application from **Jrockit 1.6** to **JVM 1.7**. here we are observing that average pause duration as well as max pause duration for CMS-Initial Mark is steadily increasing.

[image]

VM Param we are using are as below

> JAVA_OPTS="-d64 -server -Xms8g -Xmx10g -XX:NewSize=2g -XX:MaxNewSize=3g -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -verbose:gc -verbose:memory -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=86400000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=86400000 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xloggc:verbose-hotspot-server.`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:GCLogFileSize=50M -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true -XX:+PrintGCCause"

Thanks in Advance for any kind of help

Comment: Either your heap is undersized - or the young generation oversized - for your workload to meet the 40% breathing room required by your IHOP, or your application is leaking.Pls provide your GC logs for more info

Comment: 1.6? 1.7? Java 10 has been released a week ago.

Comment: Using Java 1.7.

Comment: @HashJang,we confirmed for both the things heap is not undersized nor young is undersized

Comment: Can somebody help me know why Full GC is STW and how to make that concurrent. as I have configured CMS for old collections and Major is happening using CMS only